# Can "bulge" have the following meaning?

Tags: word-usage

> Her bulge slithered to one side blanket.

Can "bulge" in this care interpreted as "the protuberance created by her"? Or it can only mean "the protuberance inside her clothes"?

Comment: "to one side blanket" is not grammatical.  "to one side *of the* blanket"

Comment: Look up *bulge* in a dictionary.  It is a *protuberance*, that is, a lump or excrescence *upon something else*.   A bulge has no existence apart from that "something else".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say bulge people are going to think you're talking about an erect penis or otherwise a protrusion from a body. *Bulge* has such a **sexual connotation** that you have to be careful what context you use it unless you want people to think you're joking.

> There was a bulge out the outside of the house after he kicked the wall

An example without sexual connotation.

> She had a bulge.

Sexual connotation. People might think you're saying she's transgender or similar.

ESPECIALLY be careful about using **slither** with **bulge**. People often refer to a penis as a snake, and since snakes slither.. you get the idea.

You could say something like:

> Her protruding body slithered to one side of the blanket.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So how to make it sound as if *she*'s the bulge inside the blanket?

Comment: Maybe: *her body was protruding though the blanket* or something similar depending on your context.

Comment: *Her protruding body slithered to one side of the blanket*. I'll add it to the answer if that works for you.

Comment: You're welcome. I added it to the answer.